# Is there a Java port or equivalent of the NEventStore library?

Tags: java, .net, cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

I've read up on [Jonathan Oliver](http://jonathanoliver.com/)'s .NET [EventStore](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/) library, and I must say the concept appeals to me a lot: having just a simple no-dependencies library which is non-intrusive and just focuses on event sourcing, leaving a lot of freedom when choosing technologies for databases, messaging, etc.

My question: Is something similar also available in the Java world?  I know there are all kind of CQRS-related frameworks, like [Axon](http://www.axonframework.org/) and [Jdon](http://jdon.org/), but those do a lot more than just event sourcing...  Anyone working on a straightforward port, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any that exist.  At the same time, it wouldn't be terribly difficult to write one.  The hardest part for me in writing the EventStore was arriving at the correct model.  I had two private/internal releases within my company, and then two public releases before I was really satisfied with how things turned out.  There are a few Ruby ports and other languages as well, and usually they take a few hours to write because the authors copy the model.  If you take the same approach, I don't see why you couldn't write your own within a few hours.

Comment: Thanks for that reply.  I found the following ports until now: [nodeEventStore](http://kaba-cceac.github.com/nodeEventStore/) in JavaScript, and [euston-eventstore](https://github.com/leemhenson/euston-eventstore) in Ruby.  If anyone knows of more: I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is old, but for those in a similar position now:
you could try Greg Young's EventStore (http://geteventstore.com)

It needs .NET or mono to run but there is a JVM-based client library:
https://github.com/EventStore/eventstorejvmclient

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Occurrent](https://occurrent.org) which is designed to be used as a library. This means that you can use only the event store, and nothing else, and add more components when you find fit.

It's also designed to integrate well with popular frameworks such as Spring Boot if you want to use a framework on top (without necessarily having to use framework-specific code in your domain model).

Answer (score -1):

In theory, it could support messaging, but appears to only support databases currently.

Using JDBC is not that much of an imposition and can wrapped up to suit your needs fairly easily.  If you want simplicity, I would use JDBC.

If you want to support JMS (messaging) I would use only that (with an adapting service to any database you want to use)  This gives you simple standard event driven interface for all types of messaging (and any database you connect to)

Comment: Could you please explain how this answers my question?  I don't get it...  The EventStore library simply allows one to commit events to a data store, have a hook called on commit (and in that hook one could send a message on a queue), and read those events back from the datastore. I'm simply looking for equivalent Java code.

Comment: So you want standard JDBC AND standard JMS. I would combine the two in a simple helper class so you can just say insert(XXX,YYY,ZZZ) so it inserts to the database and triggers a message with the same details. I could dig up some examples from the web  if you like. ;)

Comment: Either I completely misunderstand you, or the other way around.  I'm assuming you know the [EventStore](https://github.com/joliver/EventStore/) library, or at least the concept of [event sourcing](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) (see short description on the ['Domain-driven design' Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Relationship_to_other_ideas))?

Comment: You want to update the database and also notify listeners of the changes so they can handle the event/update